# Migrate from biblatex to plain bibtex

Tags: biblatex

I would like to remove the dependency on `biblatex` from a document which only uses one simple feature, namely the `\textcite` command.  Thus, I could define something like

```
\newcommand\textcite[2][]{\csname theauthorsof#2\endcsname\ \cite[#1]{#2}}
```

and then, for each `\textcite{LABEL}` in my document, add a definition like this:

```
\newcommand\theauthorsofLABEL{AUTHOR}
```

How can I automate the creation of those commands? It is allowed to use `biblatex` and `biber` to generate the author information above. However, the result should be hardcoded to my new tex files, so that the resulting document only requires the old-fashined bibtex.

Comment: Would using `natbib` be OK? In that case you could use it's `\citet` together with a numeric style.

Comment: @moewe No, I want a solution that works with any bibtex style file (bst) one might come across.

Comment: I'd say an automatic solution from within LaTeX is impossible then. LaTeX simply has no access to the author names in general (unless a particular `.bst` file provides the information in a machine readable way as is done in `natbib` and a few other style families.) May I ask why it is important that a solution should work with *all* possible `.bst` files? I can understand why you would not want to use `biblatex`, but surely `natbib` should be OK in most situations where `biblatex` has its drawback.

Comment: My goal is to use biblatex and biber (which is available on my TeX installation) to extract the author information, so that I can convert the source files to only require bibtex (and the journal's style file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer consists of three parts.

1. The first part shows why it is hard to extract metadata for any given `.bst` style automatically only from within LaTeX and explains how `natbib` (with compatible styles) manages to do that.
2. The second part shows a possible solution for non-name fields different using the `usebib` package that parses `.bib` files directly as key-value data from within LaTeX.
3. Shows a proof-of-concept `.bst` file that can extract the relevant metadata and write them to a macro so that they become usable for the fake `\textcite` proposed in the question.

## Author metadata in BibTeX bibliographies and `natbib`

There is no simple way to do this from within LaTeX for all possible BibTeX styles. But if you are willing to use `natbib` instead of pure LaTeX things will work just fine if you use `\citet` and a `natbib`-compatible style.

The main obstacle is that BibTeX styles only format the bibliography and dump a simple `thebibliography` environment into the `.bbl` file. A bibliography produced by `unsrt` might look like

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{sigfridsson}
Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde.
\newblock Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
  electrostatic potential and moments.
\newblock {\em Journal of Computational Chemistry}, 19(4):377--395, 1998.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Note that this is just the text that is going to be typeset. There is no author metadata in a format usable for LaTeX. You would have to parse the entire entry to extract the author data. While this is not impossible (I guess), I would not want to do that with LaTeX code (plus, you can't be sure of the format produced by a `.bst` file: a bibliography entry might look wildly different).

`natbib`'s author-year citations (and also its author-number `\citet`) works by passing author and year information to LaTeX in a machine-readable format. The same entry processed with `unsrtnat` will come out as (shortened)

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem[Sigfridsson and Ryde(1998)]{sigfridsson}
Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde.
\newblock Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
  electrostatic potential and moments.
\newblock \emph{Journal of Computational Chemistry}, 19\penalty0 (4):\penalty0
  377--395, 1998.
\newblock \doi{10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P}.

\end{thebibliography}
```

The `Sigfridsson and Ryde(1998)` bit in the optional argument to `\bibitem` is what LaTeX is going to use to reproduce the author and year information in the document.

If your `.bst` files does not provide these metadata it is nearly impossible to obtain them on a LaTeX side.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author  = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title   = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
             electrostatic potential and moments},
  journal = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  year    = 1998,
  volume  = 19,
  number  = 4,
  pages   = {377-395},
  doi     = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citet{sigfridsson}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

So the only solution other than using `natbib` and author-year compatible styles would involve hacking the `.bst` styles to provide the necessary information (which is possible and in many cases straightforward, but does not make things easier or more portable than just using `natbib` in the first place) or would require a different external tool that processes the `.bib` or `.bbl` to extract the necessary metadata (again, that seems like more work - see below).

---

## `usebib`

The package `usebib` would allow us to read data from the `.bib` file directly from within LaTeX. It could be very useful for cases like this, but unfortunately name fields need to be parsed by BibTeX and this name parsing is beyond the scope of `usbib`, hence

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{usebib}
\newbibfield{author}
\bibinput{\jobname}

\begin{document}
\usebibentry{sigfridsson}{author}
\end{document}
```

does not produce satisfying results. I would not want to parse the name in LaTeX, though something like this may be possible with LaTeX3 and its RegExp module (RegExps are fun, but they do not usually fare well with arbitrary LaTeX syntax because they have a poor understanding of grouping and brace levels, it might be enough for simple names, though).

---

## Use BibTeX to extract name macros from the `.bib` directly

Due to the way `biblatex` works it can't be used to write formatted data to an external file easily. Biber might be an option, but it can't be programmed to do these things as easily (and Biber decided does not do formatting, it only digests the raw data slightly). I would say that BibTeX is your best option, because BibTeX is fully equipped for the task of parsing name lists, formatting them and writing them out to a file for later use with LaTeX.

Here is a proof of concept that shows how you could use BibTeX to create the name macros for you. Naturally the output does not respond to any `biblatex` options or language settings that might have been active in your original document. That is all hard-coded in the `.bst`.

Save

```
ENTRY
  { author
    editor
    key
    year
    organization
  }
  {}
  { short.list }

STRINGS { s t }

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}

INTEGERS { len }

FUNCTION {chop.word}
{ 's :=
  'len :=
  s #1 len substring$ =
    { s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
    's
  if$
}

INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

FUNCTION {format.full.names}
{'s :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                { " et~al." * }
                { " and " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.full}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { "" }
        { editor format.full.names }
      if$
    }
    { author format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.full}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.full}
{ editor empty$
    { "" }
    { editor format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {make.full.names}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.full
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.full
        'author.full
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{ 's :=
  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  s num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$ " et~al." * }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            { " et~al." * }
            { " and " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
        'key
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            'key
          if$
        }
        { editor format.lab.names }
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.organization.label}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { organization empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            { "The " #4 organization chop.word #3 text.prefix$ }
          if$
        }
        'key
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.key.organization.label}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
        { organization empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            { "The " #4 organization chop.word #3 text.prefix$ }
          if$
        }
        'key
      if$
    }
    { editor format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {calc.short.authors}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.label
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.key.organization.label
        { type$ "manual" =
            'author.key.organization.label
            'author.key.label
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
  'short.list :=
}

FUNCTION {write.fncitedata}
{ "\expandafter\def\csname fncite@" swap$ * "@" * write$
  cite$ write$
  "\endcsname{%" write$
  newline$
  "" swap$ * "}" * write$
}

FUNCTION {output.bibinfo}
{ calc.short.authors
  short.list "labelname" write.fncitedata
  newline$
  make.full.names
  duplicate$ "" =
    'pop$
    { "fullname" write.fncitedata }
  if$
  newline$
  year
  duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    { "year" write.fncitedata }
  if$
  newline$
  newline$
}

% avoid a warning
FUNCTION {article}{}
FUNCTION {book}{}
FUNCTION {booklet}{}
FUNCTION {inbook}{}
FUNCTION {incollection}{}
FUNCTION {inproceedings}{}
FUNCTION {conference}{}
FUNCTION {manual}{}
FUNCTION {mastersthesis}{}
FUNCTION {misc}{}
FUNCTION {phdthesis}{}
FUNCTION {proceedings}{}
FUNCTION {techreport}{}
FUNCTION {unpublished}{}
FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }

READ

ITERATE {output.bibinfo}
```

as `citeauthor.bst`.

Use that file as a normal BibTeX style in your document

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author  = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title   = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
             electrostatic potential and moments},
  journal = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  year    = 1998,
  volume  = 19,
  number  = 4,
  pages   = {377-395},
  doi     = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson,geer,aksin}
\bibliographystyle{citeauthor}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

this will produce a `.bbl` like

```
\expandafter\def\csname fncite@labelname@sigfridsson\endcsname{%
Sigfridsson and Ryde}
\expandafter\def\csname fncite@fullname@sigfridsson\endcsname{%
Sigfridsson and Ryde}
\expandafter\def\csname fncite@year@sigfridsson\endcsname{%
1998}
```

You can copy this to the preamble of your document and use it as follows

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\expandafter\def\csname fncite@labelname@sigfridsson\endcsname{%
Sigfridsson and Ryde}
\expandafter\def\csname fncite@fullname@sigfridsson\endcsname{%
Sigfridsson and Ryde}
\expandafter\def\csname fncite@year@sigfridsson\endcsname{%
1998}

\newcommand\textcite[1]{\csname fncite@labelname@#1\endcsname\ \cite{#1}}

\begin{document}
\textcite{sigfridsson}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{sigfridsson}
Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde.
\newblock Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
  electrostatic potential and moments.
\newblock {\em Journal of Computational Chemistry}, 19(4):377--395, 1998.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! Before I accept, do you want to move this last bit ("Due to the way biblatex works ...") to a separate answer, for better visibility?

Comment: @FlorêncioNeves I'd rather keep everything together if that is OK with your. After all using `natbib` is the better idea if you just want to get rid of `biblatex` and the first part of the answer helps in explaining why I ended up with the proposed solution and why things work for `natbib`.